# Remove row numbers in Nattable

Tags: java, swt, nattable, nebula

I'm using Nattable for a couple of different tables in my application. Now I need to find a way to remove the row numbers in the first column. Is there some way to hide/remove the row numbers from the table?

My source to draw the table is:

```
public void generate() {
        ConfigRegistry configRegistry = new ConfigRegistry();

        ColumnGroupModel columnGroupModel = new ColumnGroupModel();
        ColumnGroupModel columnGroupGroup = new ColumnGroupModel();

        bodyLayer = new BodyLayerStack<T>(this.expandTree, getItems(), columnPropertyAccessor, configRegistry,
                treeformat);

        columnLabelAccumulator = new CustomLabelAccumulator(bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer(),
                (ListDataProvider<T>) bodyLayer.getBodyDataProvider());
        applyColumnLabels(columnDefinitions, columnLabelAccumulator);

        bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer().setConfigLabelAccumulator(columnLabelAccumulator);

        // create the column header layer stack
        IDataProvider columnHeaderDataProvider = new NATColumnHeaderDataProvider(columnDefinitions);
        DataLayer columnHeaderDataLayer = new DataLayer(columnHeaderDataProvider);

        ColumnHeaderLayer columnHeaderLayer = new ColumnHeaderLayer(columnHeaderDataLayer, bodyLayer,
                bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer());

        ILayer columnHeaderToUse = null;

        if (sortEnabled) {
            SortHeaderLayer<T> sortHeaderLayer = new SortHeaderLayer<T>(columnHeaderLayer, new GlazedListsSortModel<T>(
                    bodyLayer.getSortedList(), columnPropertyAccessor, configRegistry, columnHeaderDataLayer));

            columnGroupHeaderLayer = new ColumnGroupHeaderLayer(sortHeaderLayer, bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer(),
                    columnGroupModel);

            columnHeaderToUse = sortHeaderLayer;
        } else {
            columnGroupHeaderLayer = new ColumnGroupHeaderLayer(columnHeaderLayer, bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer(),
                    columnGroupModel);

            columnHeaderToUse = columnGroupHeaderLayer;
        }

        columnGroupGroupHeaderLayer = new ColumnGroupGroupHeaderLayer(columnGroupHeaderLayer,
                bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer(), columnGroupGroup);

        applyColumnWidths(bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer());
        applyColumnHeaderGroups();

        // Note: The column header layer is wrapped in a filter row composite.
        // This plugs in the filter row functionality
        DefaultGlazedListsStaticFilterStrategy<T> filterStrategy = new DefaultGlazedListsStaticFilterStrategy<T>(
                bodyLayer.getFilterList(), columnPropertyAccessor, configRegistry);

        for (int i = 0; i < staticFilters.size(); i++) {
            filterStrategy.addStaticFilter(staticFilters.get(i));
        }

        if (showHeaderGroupRow) {
            columnHeaderToUse = columnGroupHeaderLayer;
            if (showHeaderGroupGroupsRow)
                columnHeaderToUse = columnGroupGroupHeaderLayer;
        }

        FilterRowHeaderComposite<T> filterRowHeaderLayer = new FilterRowHeaderComposite<T>(filterStrategy,
                columnHeaderToUse, columnHeaderDataLayer.getDataProvider(), configRegistry);

        ILayer finalHeaderRow = columnHeaderToUse;
        if (showFilterRow) {
            finalHeaderRow = filterRowHeaderLayer;
        }

        // build the row header layer
        DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider rowHeaderDataProvider = new DefaultRowHeaderDataProvider(
                bodyLayer.getBodyDataProvider());
        DataLayer rowHeaderDataLayer = new DataLayer(rowHeaderDataProvider);
        rowHeaderDataLayer.setDefaultColumnWidth(40);
        ILayer rowHeaderLayer = new RowHeaderLayer(rowHeaderDataLayer, bodyLayer, bodyLayer.getSelectionLayer());

        // build the corner layer
        ILayer cornerLayer = new CornerLayer(
                new DataLayer(new DefaultCornerDataProvider(columnHeaderDataProvider, rowHeaderDataProvider)),
                rowHeaderLayer, finalHeaderRow);

        // build the grid layer
        compositeGridLayer = new GridLayer(bodyLayer, finalHeaderRow, rowHeaderLayer, cornerLayer);

        if (editorConfiguration != null) {
            compositeGridLayer.addConfiguration(editorConfiguration);
        }

        natTable = new NatTable(parent, compositeGridLayer, false);
        natTable.setConfigRegistry(configRegistry);
        natTable.addConfiguration(new DefaultNatTableStyleConfiguration());

        compositeGridLayer.registerCommandHandler(new LandscapePrintHandler(compositeGridLayer));
        addStyling();

        natTable.addLayerListener(new ILayerListener() {

            @Override
            public void handleLayerEvent(ILayerEvent event) {

                int rowNumber = -1;
                int columnNumber = -1;

                if (event instanceof CellVisualChangeEvent && !(event instanceof CellSelectionEvent)) {
                    CellVisualChangeEvent visualChangeEvent = (CellVisualChangeEvent) event;
                    rowNumber = visualChangeEvent.getRowPosition();
                    columnNumber = visualChangeEvent.getColumnPosition();

                    ListDataProvider<T> dataProvider = (ListDataProvider<T>) bodyLayer.getBodyDataProvider();

                    int transformedRow = LayerUtil.convertRowPosition(compositeGridLayer, selectedRow,
                            bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer());

                    T newObject = dataProvider.getRowObject(transformedRow);

                    notifyModificationListeners(newObject, getSelectedItem());
                }

                if (event instanceof CellSelectionEvent) {
                    CellSelectionEvent cellEvent = (CellSelectionEvent) event;
                    rowNumber = cellEvent.getRowPosition();
                    columnNumber = cellEvent.getColumnPosition();

                    launchGridSelectionUpdated();
                }

                if (rowNumber > -1) {
                    ListDataProvider<T> dataProvider = (ListDataProvider<T>) bodyLayer.getBodyDataProvider();

                    int transformedRow = LayerUtil.convertRowPosition(compositeGridLayer, rowNumber,
                            bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer());
                    T ob = dataProvider.getRowObject(transformedRow);

                    notifyItemSelectionlisteners(ob);
                }

                if (columnNumber > -1) {
                    int transformedColumn = LayerUtil.convertColumnPosition(compositeGridLayer, columnNumber,
                            bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer());
                    selectedColumnPlaceholder.clear();
                    selectedColumnPlaceholder.add(columnDefinitions.get(transformedColumn));
                }

                if (rowNumber != -1 && columnNumber != -1) {
                    // First start of the selection process
                    ListDataProvider<T> dataProvider = (ListDataProvider<T>) bodyLayer.getBodyDataProvider();

                    int transformedRow = LayerUtil.convertRowPosition(compositeGridLayer, rowNumber,
                            bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer());

                    setSelectedItem((T) Utils.cloneObject(dataProvider.getRowObject(transformedRow)));
                    selectedRow = rowNumber;
                }
            }

        });

        // add sorting configuration
        natTable.addConfiguration(new SingleClickSortConfiguration());
        natTable.configure();

        // natTable.setTheme(new ModernNatTableThemeConfiguration());

        ThemeConfiguration modernTheme = new ModernNatTableThemeConfiguration();
        modernTheme.addThemeExtension(new CustomGroupByThemeExtension());
        natTable.setTheme(modernTheme);

        freezeColumns();
        registerCopyHandlers(getSelectionLayer(), columnHeaderDataLayer);

        natTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseDown(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.button == MouseEventMatcher.RIGHT_BUTTON) {

                    int column = compositeGridLayer.getColumnPositionByX(e.x);
                    int row = bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer().getRowPositionByY(e.y);

                    row = compositeGridLayer.getRowPositionByY(e.y);
                    ListDataProvider<T> dataProvider = bodyLayer.getBodyDataProvider();
                    int transformedRow = LayerUtil.convertRowPosition(compositeGridLayer, row,
                            bodyLayer.getBodyDataLayer());

                    if (transformedRow != -1) {
                        T item = dataProvider.getRowObject(transformedRow);

                        notifyRightClickListeners(e.x, e.y, item, getColumnDefinition(column));
                    }

                }
            }
        });

        attachToolTip();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want the row numbers in the row header, don't use a `GridLayer`. You can also use a `CompositeLayer` and only have a column header and a body.

There are several examples in the NatTable examples application that show this.